# One adapter for different views and activities

Tags: android, kotlin

Can I make one adapter for two activities with different views (name and description is on first activity) and (image is another view on second activity) or would I need two separate adapters? The first activity has a button and when clicked the second activity displays the image for that item.

Comment: If the 2nd Activity just displays the detail of the item, you don't need an adapter.

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti thank you